# Facebook Messenger Bot webhook verification

Tags: python, flask, webhooks, facebook-messenger, facebook-chatbot

I am using Flask and fbmq, documentation here:https://github.com/conbus/fbmq,
for building a messenger bot.I have the correct access and verification codes but I am still getting a 404 NOT FOUND error. Here is my server.pt code:

```
from flask import Flask, request
from fbmq import Page


app = Flask(__name__)

    page = Page()
@app.route('/webhook', methods=['GET'])
def validate():
    if request.args.get('hub.mode', '') == 'subscribe' and \
                    request.args.get('hub.verify_token', '') ==   '':

        print("Validating webhook")

        return request.args.get('hub.challenge', '')
    else:
        return 'Failed validation. Make sure the validation tokens match.'


@app.route('/webhook', methods=['POST'])
def webhook():
    payload = request.get_data(as_text=True)
    print(payload)
    page.handle_webhook(payload)

    return "ok"

if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run( port=5000, debug=True, threaded=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I abandoned this project, but this was probably because I didn't add /webhook/ after my ngrok url.(I know because this solved the the problem in another project)